# python function's parameter could not use and one print error

Tags: python, sqlite

```
def readswitch(x,y,connn,read):
    x='create vlan'
    y='global'
    conn = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
    if conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        run= cur.execute("SELECT command FROM switch WHERE   function =? or type = ?  ORDER BY key ASC",(x,y))
        read = cur.fetchall()
        return run;

import database
print (database.readswitch(x,y))
```

I am trying to access the database and return command in it
I make a module called database could not print it like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/tommy/PycharmProjects/2015122/database.py", line 400, in <module>
    import database
  File "C:\Users\tommy\PycharmProjects\2015122\database.py", line 401, in <module>
    print (database.readswitch(x,y))
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

and my function parameter could not be used like

```
def readswitch(x,y,connn,read):

PEP 8: missing whitespace after ',' Parameter 'y' value is not used
```

how to fix this mistake?
I am not good at python and I need help in this few hours. Thank you!

Comment: `print (database.readswitch(x,y))` what is x and y here? They are not declared in your example code.

Comment: you haven't defined any `x,y ` before you pass them into `print (database.readswitch(x,y))` so it causes error

Comment: so what should i do now ?? How to define it well? is that means x='create vlan'
    y='global' is define nothing?

Comment: @dragon2fly do u mean I did not define x,y in my function or outside the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define a function with parameter `x,y` and then you re-assign them within a function. That makes no sense since they are not global variable nor mutable.

I suggest you remove `x,y` out of function definition or move the assignment to them out to global scope (outside the function).